# How to align sketch with the x-axis

Tags: fusion360

I have this sketch which I have accidantly rotated by some arbitary angle.

I need the dotted line to be parallel with the x-axis and the small, left hand side to be flush with the y-axis.

I've tried using the `Align` function, but can't seem to get htat to work.

Ive tried rotating the sketch, but I can't see a way to measure the angle it's off by in order to specify how far to rotate it.

I'm very new to Fusion 360, and CAD in general so it's probably something really simple.

[image: Sketch needs rotating.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather simple:

1. Start to edit the sketch with this line via a right-click `edit sketch`
2. click the line you want to force horizontal
3. on the right menu, the lower menu has "align horitontal/vertical", click it
4. DONE

To find the button I mean, a picture with the right tool next to the red mark:

[image: The alignment tool icons. Marked red: the 8th (horizontal/vertical). Marked blue: the 12th (symmetry).]

Hint: in the case of your item, I suggest to use the blue marked symmetry on the two lines you forced to be equal:

1. first choose the lines (SHIFT)
2. choose the tool
3. click the symmetry line (in your case: the construction line)